# Make nvim popup menu appear with only one character

Tags: vim, autocomplete, popup, neovim

I'm using NCM2 as my autocomplete plugin at the moment, but I'm not sure if the issue is with popup menus in general or NCM2.

When I am trying to auto-complete a filename, the pop-up menu will only appear after I've entered at least 3 characters. Even if the extra third character doesn't limit the suggestions.

Example, I have the following directory:

```
- 4822283_ERCOFTAC_m3c1_SST.dat 
- 4822299_ERCOFTAC_m3c1_SBES.log
- 4822299_FluentSBES.jou
- ERCOFTAC_m3c1_SBES.cas
- ERCOFTAC_m3c1_SBES.o4822299
- fluentSBES.sh
```

If I type in `48`, nothing comes up:

[image: 2 characters]

If I type `482`, then I get the auto-complete menu:

[image: 3 characters]

This is very consistent behavior. I at least notice it the most when dealing with file names that start with numbers.

So the question is whether I can

A) change the number of characters required for the auto complete menu to appear or

B) find whatever shortcut opens the auto-complete menu (similar to "Trigger Suggest" command in VS Code)

You can see a copy of my `init.vim` [here](https://github.com/u2berggeist/dotfiles/blob/master/nvim/init.vim).

### Edit:

Yedhin's answer addresses method A), however it also causes the auto-popup menu to be open at all times, which is fairly annoying to be honest.

For addressing item B), which would be the ideal, I found the `ncm2_manual_trigger` function. So theoretically, by putting the following in `init.vim`, you can manual trigger the auto-popup at anytime.

```
let g:ncm2#auto_popup = 0
imap <C-a> <Plug>(ncm2_manual_trigger)
```

However, as detailed in [this issue posted on the ncm2 repo](https://github.com/ncm2/ncm2/issues/70), the manual_trigger is still dependent on the `ncm2#complete_length` parameter to figure out what to display. This causes the manual trigger to not display the popup-menu if the auto-trigger hasn't already triggered the popup-menu. We'll just have to wait for the issue to be resolved for now (which as of writing should be fairly soon judging off the "my-next-task" tag on the issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try explicitly setting this in you init.vim :

```
let g:ncm2#complete_length=[[1,1],[7,2]]
```

So this value means that sources with priority between 1 and 6 will have the value of 1, and sources with priority >=7 will have the value of 2.

Comment: Since you apparently know your way around `ncm2` (or at least know how to google things better than I do), any idea how to do method B? I tried the way to do it for omnicomplete (`<C-X> <C-O>`), but it comes up with the error `E764: Option 'omnifunc' not set`.

Comment: I believe omnifunc works depending on the filetype. so you have to explicitly set the ominfunc, [like described in the documentation](https://github.com/ncm2/ncm2#optional-vimrc-tips).  I cant guarantee this for sure, because the manual triggers as you've mentioned above is a WIP for ncm2.